# Why is Sweetify not working on my project?

Tags: python, django

Sweetify does not work in my project.
I went ahead according to document but it does not work
Does anyone know what the problem is?

this is my view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHF1v.png)

Comment: "it does not work" is very vague, please explain exactly what the issue is and add the full traceback to your question in you are getting an error

Comment: Don't share your code as an image, but as a snippet, and explain what "doesn't work" mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps and please check the code that I answered.

- pip install --upgrade sweetify
- Check INSTALLED_APPS section in settings.py

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'sweetify' ]
  ```
- Be sure you imported sweetify in views.py

  ```
  import sweetify
  ```

If all are them is okay try this on your function .

```
    sweetify.error(request, 'You did it', text='Error', persistent='Error')
```

Comment: I've done all the steps you said, and I load the inside of the file layout, but doesn't work

Comment: If you can let us see what is the error? what does the error say? We can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

Sweetify does not provide client side files of SweetAlert. [See the note in installation section](https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify-django#installation). Add the following code to your base or layout page.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the {% block content %} of your template file where you want to display the sweetalert, add:

```
{% for message in Messages %}
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"> </script>
  {% if message.tags == 'info' %}
       <script>
           var m = "{{ message }}";
           swal("Blocked !", m, "info");
       </script>
  {% elif message.tags == 'error' %}
       <script>
           var m = "{{ message }}";
           swal("Denied!", m, "error")
       </script>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```